# Can't find "Google Sign-In" in developer console

Tags: google-signin, google-plus-signin

I want to integrate Google Sign-In into my Android application, I'm following Google guidelines for this, and worked for me to integrate the Google Plus in my application but I needed to add Plus as scope to my code. But, I want just the Google Sign-In for the application, I don't need Google Plus functionality.

In the developer console of my application when I enable services I can never find "Google Sign-In" as service to be enabled. I only find "Google+ API".

I can see the "Google Sign-In" in Google posts, I'm referring to a recent blog by Google [Registering OAuth clients for Google Sign-In](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html)

Appreciate if someone can help, or clear this confusion.

Comment: did you follow https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating ?

Comment: yes of course, my issue is in the developer console, I can't find the Google Sign-In API shown in figure 2 [Registering OAuth clients for Google Sign-In](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html)

Comment: Click "Get a configuration file" at https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In

Comment: It seems to be doing it, but I was using another site https://console.developers.google.com    what is the entry point from http://developers.google.com ? Why it is not there in the console that have lots of functionality, can u clear the confusion?